# Regex combine multiple repeating groups into one group

Tags: regex

I'd like to make a Regex "script", that would help me abbreviate sentences.

So far I've made this expression `(?:^| |-|_)([A-Z])`, but it only returns one letter for the match.

I wondered if there was a way for me to combine all those found letters into one group.

Example sentences:

```
This Is Amazing -> TIA
How Does This Work -> HDTW
I Am Leaving The House -> IALTH
```

There is no specific language yet, but because GoLang and few others don't support look-arounds, the answer without those would be preferred.

Comment: Do you have to match (and join) all upper-case letters, or could you also remove (substitute with empty string) all _other_ characters? The latter might be easier.

Comment: Either would work, as I don't really care about lower-case letters.

Comment: Does it have to be the *start* of each word, or only if it starts with an uppercase?

Comment: Might be better to use `(?:\b|_|-)(\w)`. `\w`matches all word-characters(a-zA-Z0-9) and `\b`is a word boundary. Can't you just concat all matches with go?

Comment: @Chrᴉz this is a good point - what about numbers? `I Am 12 Years Old`, for example?

Comment: @VLAZ Only OP can secify that :). As he wrote each letter upper case, I expect the examples to be simplified and include them as well.

Comment: @Chrᴉz you are correct, examples are simplified and each word starts with a capital letter. Yes, I could combine it with Go, and I'm doing that right now, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with Regex.

Comment: @NickReed you're correct, it is a duplicate. Somehow it didn't show up when I googled it and when I typed in the title.
Chrᴉz, VLAZ, NickReed, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, this is not possible.

Capture groups can't be combined in this way - that responsibility is left up to whatever programming language you're working with. As far as I know, a single regex alone isn't powerful enough to first remove letters and then group the results into one capture group. You would have to first get the letters together as a set of groups, and then use a second regex to "capture" them all.

If you want to do that, the following regex works:

`(\b\w\K)\w* *`

This regex will capture the first letter of each word in a sentence. It also matches trailing space characters / any extra spaces in your sentence.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/yRj38B/4/)

Comment: Small point: Truncating numbers is odd - try it with `I Am 12 Years Old`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work for me, as it removes ONLY first letters in each word and adds the rest to it's own group https://i.imgur.com/nz2voFp.png

Comment: What's `\K`? Regex101 doesnt recognize it.

Comment: @Chrᴉz "*`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match*" - it says it on the site - look at the upper right.

Comment: @MGlolenstine see updated answer and link - I'd assumed you were removing captured letters, my bad.

Comment: @NickReed I've checked it, but it still does a similar thing than mine above. It separates the matches into different matches. I was asking if there was a way to group them into one match.

Comment: Ah, Now I understand the question. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, but not in GoLang. OP said he has no selected language yet, true. He just mentioned it as a possible language. -> no problem yet

Comment: @MGlolenstine updated, though probably not what you were hoping to hear - regex alone isn't powerful enough to do what you're hoping.

Comment: An alternative is to capture the first letter of each word and continually re-run the regex against the input until all matches are exhausted. But yeah, you can't just capture all of them at once.

Comment: @NickReed and @VLAZ You're correct, it's not something I was hoping to hear, but as the captured groups can usually be combined with `$0` and `$1`, I was hoping that there was a way to do it with repeating groups.